# Como modificar um objeto Json (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Preciso alterar um Objeto json que estou recebendo. Gostaria de inserir um dado de uma input nesse Json.
A ideia é simples coloco um dado, ele puxa o json de acordo com esse dado, mas preciso mudar o json com esse mesmo dado. Preciso mudar o johnner no apiGet!
Segue Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Meu Projeto</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>
Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" value="johnner">

<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="teste()">Try it</button>
<p id="saida">aqui</p>

<script>

function teste() {
     var x = document.getElementById("nome").value;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/br/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + 
 x + "?api_key=a15c56d1-fdd7-4da2-ad9c-0f1a6585ac1b";

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        apiGet(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

function apiGet(response) {
    var XX = JSON.parse(response);
    var arr = XX.johnner;
    var out = "<h1>";
    out += arr.id + arr.name + arr.summonerLevel;
    out += "</h1>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

function getImput() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nome").value;
document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Preciso mudar/aceder ao Json desta parte: `var arr = XX.johnner;` usando o mesmo nome que foi passado no url do ajax.

O AJAX retorna isto:

```
{"johnner":{"id":1111,"name":"Johnner","profileIconId":111,"summonerLevel":11,"revisionDate":1111111111}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que precisas é usar a variável `x` dentro da função `apiGet` para poderes aceder à propriedade do objeto dinamicamente, ou seja com parenteses retos `[]`.

Sugiro mudares o código como no exemplo em baixo, que resumindo tem estas duas alterações:

- chama `apiGet` passando também `x` como parâmetro
- usa `var arr = XX[x];` acedendo assim à propriedade com a string que passaste

JavaScript

```
function teste() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/br/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" +
    x + "?api_key=a15c56d1-fdd7-4da2-ad9c-0f1a6585ac1b";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      apiGet(xmlhttp.responseText, x);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function apiGet(response, nome) {
  var XX = JSON.parse(response);
  var obj = XX[nome];
  var out = "<h1>";
  out += obj.id + obj.name + obj.summonerLevel;
  out += "</h1>";
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Nota: mudei no código também `var arr` para `var obj` uma vez que o JSON te dá um objeto e não uma array. Assim fica mais correto para quem lê o código (semânticamente).

Comment: Perfeito Sergião!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Era isso mesmo que eu queria! Me falta muito conhecimento ainda!! Vou modificar ainda toda a nomenclatura colocar json no lugar de XX talvez e acrescentar mais coisas. Ainda estou me aprofundando.

Comment: :) fico content de ter ajudado (@Johnner)