# Existe como transformar uma string como caminho?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var sql = {
    datatypes: {

        integer:
        {
            INT: {
                mysql: 'INT'
            },
            SMALLINT: {
                mysql: 'SMALLINT'
            }
        }
    }
}

// Funciona
alert(sql.datatypes.integer.SMALLINT.mysql);

// Não funciona
teste("SMALLINT");
function teste(type){
     alert(sql.datatypes.integer.type.mysql);
}
```

Comment: Duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101938/129 (como aceder a propriedades de um JSON/Objeto dinamicamente)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Como você está enviando uma string, basta mudar para o modo de seleção para:

```
sql.datatypes.integer[type].mysql
```

```js
var sql = {
    datatypes: {

        integer:
        {
            INT: {
                mysql: 'INT'
            },
            SMALLINT: {
                mysql: 'SMALLINT'
            }
        }
    }
}

// Funciona
alert(sql.datatypes.integer.SMALLINT.mysql);

// Funciona também
teste("SMALLINT");
function teste(type){
     alert(sql.datatypes.integer[type].mysql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar um atributo com a chave como string você deve utilizar colchetes `[]`:

```
sql.datatypes.integer[type].mysql
```

Comment: @jbueno valeu, sempre confundo os dois haha